# The udp server throws OOM exception when feed data in a high rate

Tags: java, out-of-memory, netty

In order to recieve the maximum 64kb of data and reduce the packets loss, I config a udp server like the following with netty 4.0

```
public class UdpServer {

    public void run()
        throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
            b.group( group ).channel( NioDatagramChannel.class ).option( ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true )
                .option( ChannelOption.UDP_RECEIVE_PACKET_SIZE, 1024 * 64 )
                .option( ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 1024 * 1024 * 100 ).handler( new UserHandler() );

            b.bind( 5141 ).sync().channel().closeFuture().await();
        }
        finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
        throws Exception {
        new UdpServer().run();
    }
}
```

When I feed data in 20kmsg/s to the udp sercer, it throws the OOM exception.
I found the cause is that the config param for UDP_RECEIVE_PACKET_SIZE is too larger so that the direct buffer memory is ran out quickly. If I set 1024*128 to SO_RCVBUF, 1024 * 2 to UDP_RECEIVE_PACKET_SIZE, the server works well when I feed data in 20kmsg/s.

Are there any suggestion to avoid the OOM excepiton when the UDP_RECEIVE_PACKET_SIZE does not change?

Thanks for any help/insight

Comment: Would it be possible to upload the heapdump to see why the references are not cleaned up.

Comment: The heapdump is too large, and I can't find a way to upload it here. With jvisualvm I find that the direct buffer memory always increase to high value when I begin to feed the data. I think the cause is that there are too many data so that the method AbstractNioMessageChannel.doReadMessages() always can read data, so the  free flag is always false and  the data  can't been released in the method NioDatagramChannel.doReadMessages().

Comment: Sounds like some possible problem let me open an issue and fix it in betty

Comment: Could you please re-test with latest 4.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT? It should be fixed now.... See https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1388

Comment: The fix can resovle my question.                                  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Was a bug and is fixed in latest master and so will be part of Netty 4.0.0.Final.

See http://github.com/netty/netty/issues/1388

Comment: In Netty4.0.0.CR5, this problem comes back, I see the first fix has been reverted. Could you give me some ideas to resolve this problem again?Thanks